# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Django CSRF cookie not set

Tags: django, cookies, csrf, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu(64-bit) on VirtualBox(5.0.10) for the test environment. When i try to execute an Ajax post request, i get 'Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)'.

But the same post action in my web application works fine under the development environment on OS X. I doubt that it is a bug in the new Ubuntu release.

Anyone has any idea why could this happen?

Thanks.

Edit:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{% url 'add-new-watch-folder' %}',
            data: {
                dirs: dirsJSON,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you try use some plugin like postman to see any different between two machine?

Comment: It is a simple post action so i didnt need. When i check the cookies on test environment, i saw that 'csrftoken' and 'sessionid' cookies were not set. That is the difference actually. But dont know why.

Comment: Please post your code for Ajax call and the function  to get CSRF token

Comment: @Aison Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in your system, the development environment hides some security mechanisms.

You can find answers about how to use POST on AJAX an get the CSRF token in [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/).

You may also use GET, which doesn't need CSRF token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Can you be more explanatory with what security mechanisms does development environment hides? Besides the problem is on the test environment as you may haven't read the question.

I stated in my question that the POST request works fine on the development environment so basically i already know how to make a POST request with AJAX in a Django web application.

And also you shouldn't use GET request where a POST is needed.